# Understanding why SPF breaks forwarding

Tags: email, spf

I'm having trouble understanding why SPF breaks forwarding.
Say my mail is me@domain.com, and I'm send an email to joe@mit.edu.
Assume that Joe configured his mit.edu account to forward mail to his personal account, joe@gmail.com. 
Now I would expect the SMTP conversion between my domain's MTA and mit.edu's MTA to look something like that:

```
220 mit.edu.ac.il
HELO domain.com
250 OK
MAIL FROM: <me@domain.com>
250 OK
RCPT TO: <joe@mit.edu>
...
```

I have 2 questions:
1) Now when the mail is forwarded, what will be the MAIL FROM value? I assume it'll be the same, and therefore will fail the SPF because ns.domain.com doesn't allow mit.edu to send emails using its domain.
2) If I'm correct in 1, why not just set MAIL FROM to be the forwarder's identity (is this case, mit.edu)?

Answer (score 0):

Classic email forwarding standards (e.g. `~/.forwward`) had been created well before spam era.  They keep envelope sender (`MAIL FROM:`) unchanged => it may cross restrictions imposed via SPF record.

Some forwarding methods (e.g. procmail, `~/.procmailrc`) allow to forward with new/changed `MAIL FROM:`.

*SO* you should be very specific about MTA/SMTP server doing forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Relaying is handled by [SRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme), but that's not the same thing as forwarding. What you're asking for is essentially forgery, so SPF doesn't like it. The solution is not to attempt to preserve the from address, because it's a forward, not a relay.